# HTML auto page-breaks for Print

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to print an invoice that has multiple tables. One table(in which items are listed) has a dynamic content. I am unable to give explicit page breaks as the content is dynamic. When i print the invoice, the table's boxes are split and half of a line is printed on one page and the other half on the next page. How to style the print? Is there any way of giving auto page breaks?

Comment: Google it [HTML line break](https://www.google.iq/search?q=html+page+break&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

Answer (score 1):

CSS rules `page-break-after`, `page-break-before` and `page-break-inside` should help you.

In particular, you may add `page-break-inside: avoid` to your `<table>` to prevent it from breaking.

Note: these CSS rules may only **try** to avoid breakings, and may not work in situations such as a table longer than one page.